# Combine database tables and to form into one table

Tags: html, mysql

I have two tables, one is Customer Detail and the other is Order Detail. Each time the Customer will order something it will store it in database. How can I find which customer orders and how many times they order and combine the customer name and orders?

```
CUSTOMER DETAIL:

ID  NAME        AGE COUNTRY
1   AAA     22  US
2   BBB     26  UK
3   CCC     25  TN


ORDER DETAIL:

ID  ITEMS   PRICE QUANTITY
1   APPLE   5
1   ORANGE  6
1   MANGO   4
```

Customer AAA has many orders.

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
CUSTOMERDETAIL  ORDERDETAIL
AAA (HOW MANY TIMES HE ORDER AND ORDER DETAILS)
```

Comment: If you have the customer ID in both tables you can use the `JOIN` clause. But we have no idea about the schema of your DB.

Comment: Provide your schema and required output.

Comment: u need to keep customerid as ref col in ur order detail table. So whenever u insert order details u will insert customerid as well. Later on if u want to retrieve data join both tables based on customerid. See more details on google for primary key and reference key.

Comment: @ShahidIqbal just look at my question.thanks for your reply.

Comment: @NickR just look my question.

Comment: where is CustomerDetailId in Order Detail, no relation ship exists between two tables.??

Comment: included customer id as a foreign key in order detail is that right?.

Comment: yes, i have send an answer to you, try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     Create Table Customer (CustomerId int identity(1,1),Name varchar(20))
     Create Table OrderDetail(OrderDetailId int identity(1,1), CustomerId int, Item varchar(20), Quantity int)

    Insert into Customer values('AAA')
    Insert into Customer values('BBB')
    Insert into Customer values('CCC')

    Insert into OrderDetail values(1,'Apple',10)
    Insert into OrderDetail values(1,'Banana',10)
    Insert into OrderDetail values(1,'Mango',10)

    select y.total, x.Item,x.quantity from
    (
    select c.customerId as customerId, d.Item, d.quantity from customer c inner join orderdetail d
    on      c.customerId = d.customerId
    )x
    inner join 
    (
        select customerid, COUNT(customerId)as total from orderdetail group by customerId
    )y
    on x.customerId = y.customerId
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the schema like this:

Customer table (customer)

```
ID (Customer Id) int primary key
Name varchar(100)
```

Order Table (orders)

```
ID (Order ID) int
cusotmer_id (reference id of customer table primary key-ID) int
quality int
price float
```

**First Count of Order against eash customer:**

```
select count(o.customer_id) as total_order, c.* from customer c left join orders o on c.ID = o.customer_id
```

**Orders listing against a single customer:**

`select c.*, o.* from customer c` inner join orders o on c.ID = o.customer_id where c.ID = 1

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The following query gives what i expect.

SELECT name,items,price FROM customerdetail INNER JOIN orderdetail ON customerdetail .sno=orderdetail .id WHERE id=1 ;